# How to update an attribute without touch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid3

Is there an option to not touch the `updated_at` attribute when i update an attribute in mongoid ?

Something similar to `model.save(validate: false)` or, better, `model.update_attribute(:attribute, 'value')` ?

Comment: You can do it outside of active record assuming you're using Rails.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816900/how-to-query-mongodb-directly-from-ruby-instead-of-using-mongoid#17537735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my answer here : https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/v3.1.7/lib/mongoid/timestamps/timeless.rb

If anyone is interested, you can use `model.timeless` to skip updating created or update date, and `model.clear_timeless_option` to reactivate it !

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `update_column` method:

https://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column

Validations are skipped.

Callbacks are skipped.

updated_at/updated_on are not updated.

Comment: `update_column` is available for ActiveRecord but not for MongoID