# How to safe_constantize a class that doesn't exist in the Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-5

To query my MongoDB database I call:

```
MyClass.collection.find({ foo: "bar" })
```

If I want to constantize `MyClass` from a string I call:

```
"MyClass".safe_constantize.collection.find({ foo: "bar" })
```

This will return an array that I can work with. The array contains hash-like objects of the class `BSON::Document`.

But what if I want to query for a class that exists in the db, but not in my Rails app?

If I call `"UnknownClass".safe_constantize` it returns `nil`.

If I could move past that point I would have an array of regular key/value pairs to work with, and it wouldn't be a problem that the original class that was stored inside the db was unknown to my Rails app.

So how do I query for a class that my Rails app don't know about?

Comment: Are you trying to say that table exist but you did not have model for that table right?

Comment: are you using mongoid or something else?

Comment: Why constantize at all? Why not just build a query and submit as SQL?

Comment: @AjayBarot correct the table exists in the db. It just doesn't exist in my Rail app as a model. There is a good reason for that, but it seems unnecessary to go into that.

Comment: @Anthony I'm using the [Mongo driver](http://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html) to query. Mongoid doesn't fit my use case for a few reasons.

Comment: @AjayBarot I would need an example, but `"MyClass".safe_constantize.collection.find({ foo: "bar" })` fits my use case in many ways, except for this constantization problem, so my question is quite specifically about how to make this `collection.find` query work.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976: Please check the answer, probably it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Please let me know If its not working

```
sql = "SELECT * from unknown_table"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
result.collection.find({ foo: "bar" })
```

Edit:

This is not working because you are using `mongoid` thus you don't have rails `ActiveRecord`. You can try this if you are using Mongoid 3 or above.

```
db = Mongoid::Sessions.default

# inserting a new document
collection = db[:collection_name]
collection.find({ foo: "bar" }
```

Ref: [How to query MongoDB directly from Ruby instead of using Mongoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14816900/2681997)

Comment: when running line 2 I get `NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord`.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer. For some reason I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Mongoid::Sessions`. There is a comment in the SO post you refer to about this, but I can't make any sense of it.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976: Are you testing this on rails console?

Comment: Please do this if you are testing this on rails console `require 'mongoid'` and `Mongoid.load!("path/to/your/mongoid.yml")` after that do as above mention.

Comment: Hm strange, it doesn't seem to help. Aside from the console I also ran the line of code in the app at runtime.

Comment: Hm strange, it doesn't seem to help. Aside from the console I also ran the line of code in the app at runtime.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976: Please attach gemfile which shows mongoid gems in question.

Comment: `    mongo (2.2.5)
      bson (~> 4.0)
    mongoid (5.1.3)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
      mongo (~> 2.1)
      origin (~> 2.2)
      tzinfo (>= 0.3.37)`

Comment: It seems the connection gets establish differently depending on what mongoid version you run, but the overall answer seems to be correct. For me it worked with `db = Mongoid::Clients.default`.